# Orchrestrate multiple Azure Functions (powershell & C#)

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-powershell, azure-function-app

I have 2 Azure Functions - Powershell. One will Resume a PowerBI Embedded Capacity and the other will Pause it.

Then I have 1 Azure Function - C# that has to run once the PowerBI Embedded Capacity is running.

So in order to do that I will need an Orchestrator function that does the following:

1. Await Powershell function until the PowerBI Embedded is running
2. Await C# function to do some tasks
3. Await Powershell function to Pause PowerBI Embedded

I was looking into this code but I guess this will work only when all your functions are C# and within the same Function App. Because I have C# and Powershell I have 2 Function Apps.

```
[FunctionName("E1_HelloSequence")]
public static async Task<List<string>> Run(
    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)
{
    var outputs = new List<string>();

    outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("E1_SayHello", "Tokyo"));
    outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("E1_SayHello", "Seattle"));
    outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>("E1_SayHello_DirectInput", "London"));

    // returns ["Hello Tokyo!", "Hello Seattle!", "Hello London!"]
    return outputs;
}
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Durable Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp) currently supports the following languages:

> **C#**: both precompiled class libraries and C# script.
>   **JavaScript**: supported only for version 2.x of the Azure Functions runtime. Requires version 1.7.0 of the Durable Functions extension, or a later version.
>   **F#**: precompiled class libraries and F# script. F# script is only supported for version 1.x of the Azure Functions runtime.

**It does not support function with powershell now**. If you want this feature, you can give your voice to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions) to prompt it to be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

Durable PowerShell Functions are going to be in Public Preview soon, and you can try them out now by using these [instructions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/blob/dev/docs/durable-experimental-instructions.md). You can also watch the progress and leave your feedback [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-powershell-worker/issues/77).

However, your orchestrator function and activity functions must reside the same Function app, but you cannot mix PowerShell and C# functions in the same app. I would suggest converting the C# function into PowerShell: perhaps you can rewrite this code in PowerShell, or wrap the C# code into a PowerShell module, or use the `Add-Type` cmdlet to inject C# code into PowerShell. Alternatively, convert your PowerShell functions into C# functions.